# Google My Business API 403 permission denied

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am following this guide https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup?authuser=3#make-simple-http-request

to make simple HTTP request using OAuth 2.0 Playground. But after following and completing all the steps. I get 403 permission denied error:

[image: Google My Business API 403 permission denied]

Can anyone help me to understand what other steps necessary to successfully make API request?

Comment: we got this same problem bro. did you resolve it?